# How to optimize the ruby code iterates several integers in a range?

Tags: ruby

New to Ruby, and trying to find a 3 digits number "abc":

```
for a in 0..9
    for b in 0..9
        for c in 0..9
            if a*a+b*b+c*c == (100*a+10*b+c)/11.0
                puts "#{a}#{b}#{c}"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This is too lengthy, is any way to optimize it, or write it in another "ruby" way?

Comment: You can condense the code, but given what you want to achieve, you will still need to keep the three loops. Any optimization will not have a huge effect

Comment: This already runs quite fast (90 ms on my machine). Do you show us actual code or simply an example? In the above case i would simply hardcode the numbers `000, 550, 803`, because the output is always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%2a+a+%2B+b+%2a+b+%2B+c+%2a+c+%3D%3D+%28100+%2a+a+%2B+10+%2a+b+%2B+c%29+%2F+11.0) :)

Here's another fun solution. Not really faster, just more compact and perhaps more ruby-like if that was what you were looking for:

```
(0..9).to_a.repeated_permutation(3).select { |a,b,c| 
  a*a+b*b+c*c == (100*a+10*b+c)/11.0 
}
=> [[0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 0], [8, 0, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to finding a,b,c such that

```
100*a + 10*b + c = 11 * (a*a + b*b +c*c)
```

i.e. `100*a + 10*b + c` must be divisible by 11. Simple number theory tells you that when a,b,c are digits, this means that

```
`a + c - b`
```

must be a multiple of 11 so

```
`a + c = b or a + c = 11 +b`
```

So for a given values of a and b you only need to check two values of c : b -a and 11 +b -a rather than 10. You can cut the search space in two again: if a > b you only need to check the latter of those two values and if a <= b you need only check the former.

Thus instead of checking 1000 triplets of numbers you should only need to check 100, which should be 10 times faster.

```
for a in 0..9
  for b in 0..9
    if a > b
      c = 11 +b -a
    else
      c = b - a
    end
    if a*a+b*b+c*c == (100*a+10*b+c)/11.0
      puts "#{a}#{b}#{c}"
    end
  end
end
```